# How to virtually send an receive CAN Signals on AOSP emulator

Tags: android-source, can-bus

Need to receive CAN Signals on AOSP emulator which are created virtually.

Not found any way to send or rercive CAN Signals virtually

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an abstraction that allows you to "inject" virtual CAN signals into your event processing queue.